# LongPress dosent get trigered

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I installed the Xamarin community toolkit, and I am trying to play a message to the user when long pressing the item, but for some reason, it doesn't trigger. I want to send the selected item as a parameter, and delete it
I added a little portion of the ViewModel, and the binding context is set in code behind

```
        <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="CarsList"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListPage}, Path = BindingContext.PressedCommand}"
                              xct:TouchEffect.CommandParameter="{Binding .}">

                        <local:CarView Padding="0,10,0,0" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

```
public Command PressedCommand
    {
        get; set;
    }




    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        PressedCommand = new Command(PressAction);
        GridSpan = Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone ? 1 : 2;
        BuildCars();
    }

    private void PressAction(object obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    private void LongAction(object obj)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Warning", "do you want to delete?", "OK");
    }

    .....

    private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;

    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            return _cars;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _cars, value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) you are binding to a command named `LogProess` but that doesn't exist in your VM, 2) if you want to bind to anything on the base VM from within a ListView, you need to use a relative binding

Comment: I update the UI and VM, but it doesn't work

Comment: `...LongPressCommand="{Binding BindingContext.LongPressCommand, Source={x:Reference CarsList}}"`

Comment: as @ToolmakerSteve points out, you fixed #1 but did not address #2.

Comment: I did and nothing really happend

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Could you chek my update and let me know, what I did wrong

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with code you show. Probably something missing somewhere else.  First get a simpler case working. Such as a touch that is NOT inside a collection. Seems like your view isn't correctly hooked to your viewmodel. Countless previous questions and answers on this topic. Search.

Comment: if you are passing an argument to the command, I believe that you need to use `Command<T>`

Comment: well I could put Selection mode to single and of course, it works, but want I want to do is to use the toolkit to have long-press and thing

Comment: Can you check if you are binding the correct BindingContext (source)?